# rJava error message: cannot allocate vector of size

Tags: r, size, rjava

Wondering whether you met this before: I installed `rJava` package in R (R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)) on a 64 bit windows system. And when I tried to load this package, I got this error message:

```
library(rJava)

Error : cannot allocate vector of size 3.8 Gb
  In addition: Warning messages:
  1: package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.1.3 
  2: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) :
     Reached total allocation of 4028Mb: see help(memory.size)
  3: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) :
     Reached total allocation of 4028Mb: see help(memory.size)
  4: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) :
     Reached total allocation of 4028Mb: see help(memory.size)
  5: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) :
     Reached total allocation of 4028Mb: see help(memory.size)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

Comment: First, you really should upgrade your version of R.

Comment: What gets returned when you type `memory.limit()`?

Comment: @AlexWoolford   I got 4028 using memory.limit().